# JavaScript Object Array Not Pushing Properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, splice

I have an Array (oldArray) of 120 objects.
I want to make another Array (newArray) whose first element is the first element of oldArray.
Seems simple enough, except that my outputs are not as expected.

```
var obj = oldArray[0];
newArray[0] = obj;
console.log(obj);
console.log(newArray);
console.log(newArray[0]);
console.log(oldArray);
console.log(oldArray[0]);
```

`obj`, `newArray[0]`, and `oldArray[0]` all produce the same result in my console -- the single object that I want to work with.

`newArray` however shows all objects of `oldArray`, not just the one that I thought obj contained. `newArray.length == 1`. Console displays: [Object]

`oldArray` is my original array. `oldArray.length == 120`. Console displays [Object, Object, ...]

I have tried many things and did not expect to get hung up on this. I thought it would have been `newArray.push(oldArray[0])` or maybe `newArray[0] = oldArray.splice(0,1)` but everything I attempt seems to be creating the same issue.

Is there some kind of special trick for working with arrays of Objects?

Thanks!

Comment: it looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YK5aW/1/

Comment: Are both `newArray` and `oldArray` declared as an Array?

Comment: Ok, turns out that some stuff I was doing with newArray later on was messing it up, but for some reason that console.log was showing a LATER version of newArray (I had no other console.logs anywhere else). Thing works perfectly. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried replicating your issue and these are my results:

```
var oldArray = ['a','b','c','d'];
var newArray = [];

var obj = oldArray[0]; // store the first value in a new variable
newArray[0] = obj; // push the variable's value to the first index of the new array

console.log(obj);
    // 'a'
console.log(newArray);
    // ['a']
console.log(newArray[0]);
    // 'a' (the same as obj)
console.log(oldArray);
    // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
console.log(oldArray[0]);
    // 'a'
```

Based on the scope of the script and the data in `oldArray`, these is correct behaviour. Either your test case isn't reduced properly or the problem isn't reflected by your question.

Since I was testing with strings and not objects, there may be some differing behaviour in your specific use case, but giving some sample data about the contents of `oldArray` would greatly help your cause.

Comment: I am certain that there is something more going on with my code. Both are arrays but when I test typeof, I get 'object'. Is that normal?

Comment: In JS, both objects and arrays have a typeof `"object"`. The difference between them can be assessed by doing `item.length`. Objects have an `undefined` length, and arrays will be `0` or larger.